# How to send token in CoAP requests?

Tags: http, authentication, authorization, coap

Is there a consensus on how to send tokens as part of CoAP requests?

HTTP clients share their identity/credentials through the *Authorization* header (or eventually the *Cookie* header) or less often as part of the URL (e.g. a JSON Web Token encoded in base64url). In the [CoAP RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7252), there is not equivalent option to *Authorization*.

Draft profiles for authentication and authorization for constrained environments (e.g. [OSCORE](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-ietf-ace-oscore-profile/) or [DTLS](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-ietf-ace-dtls-authorize/)) rely on the underlying security protocol to maintain a stateful connection and the token is uploaded to `/authz-info` once:

```
      C                            RS                   AS
      | [-- Resource Request --->] |                     |
      |                            |                     |
      | [<---- AS Request  ------] |                     |
      |      Creation Hints        |                     |
      |                            |                     |
      | ----- POST /token  ----------------------------> |
      |                            |                     |
      | <---------------------------- Access Token ----- |
      |                           + Access Information   |
      | ---- POST /authz-info ---> |                     |
      |     (access_token, N1)     |                     |
      |                            |                     |
      | <--- 2.01 Created (N2) --- |                     |
```

However, this is not suitable for unprotected environment (e.g. for development or in a private network). Since CoAP is typically on top of UDP, it is not possible to have "sessions" so we cannot track which client uploaded which token. I'd like to avoid to discuss about usefulness of token in unprotected context.

Should the token be part of the URI (i.e. as a `Uri-Query` option or in the `Uri-Path`)? ThingsBoard is an example of service having the the [token as part of the `Uri-Path`](https://thingsboard.io/docs/reference/coap-api/) but I'm not sure if this is the best option. Also, would sending a binary [CBOR Web Token](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc8392/) in `Uri-Query` be possible without base64url encoding?

Comment: Do you require such an access token for other "cloud micro services"? If yes, HTTP(S) clients sends such tokens (mostly :-) ) on every request. I'm not sure, if your intention to store such tokens in a session will anyway break the considered security. I'm even not sure, if a system, where you authorize your coap-clients with either DTLS (coaps) or even simple client IDs (plain coap) and then generate these access tokens on your RS/AS for the request to other "cloud micro services" would lower the considered security more than the session. But that depends on your own considerations.

Comment: Just, if you don't want the tokens for passing them to other "cloud micro services" but you want to use them for you own access control mechanism. There is something similiar for more fine grained access control, see [echo-request-tag](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-ietf-core-echo-request-tag), that is something you may consider.

Comment: @AchimKraus Yes, cloud services is a use case I have in mind. Could you elaborate on how you would take advantage of the _echo-request-tag_ spec? Are you talking about the Request-Tag option specifically?

Comment: Using plain coap, the client is mainly identified by it's ip-address. With the request-tag, you may validate that ip-address, if a specifc resource requires such a address validation. But sure, that is not comparable with tokens passed over https. It really depends much on your security considerations, if DTLS should not be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CoAP, no attempt is made to provide user authentication without a security layer in place, nor are there provisions for sessions in the CoAP layer (which would violate the REST design).

As I understand, that was a conscious decision to guide implementers towards a RESTful design, and to avoid the transfer of security tokens over unsecured transports.

For the two use case of "during development", it is possible to introduce an own CoAP option in the experimental-use range, for example "65003 = Simulated-OSCORE-Key-ID" (where 65003 is chosen to be critical and not safe to forward). While the OSCORE stack is not operational, an ad-hoc made-up OSCORE key ID could be inserted there and then have a token POSTed using it in the ACE steps. Obviously, those constructs should neither make their way out of a test setup, and not into specifications.

Private networks are considered as untrusted ("NoSec mode") as the rest of the network in CoAP. That assumption can probably be understood better in the context of the principle of least authority, which makes setups where all devices (and processes) on a network share the same set of permissions highly unlikely.